# Is this really an open problem? Maximizing angle between $n$ vectors

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, open-problem

It is well known that the [trigonal planar molecule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_planar_molecular_geometry) (with bond angle $\alpha=120^{\circ}$) and the famous [tetrahedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_molecular_geometry) (with bond angle $\alpha\approx 109.5^{\circ}$) maximizes the angle between the vectors pointing along the bonds. So the question is this:

> How do we (analytically) maximize the angle between $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Or put differently:

> What is the maximum distance that one of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ can be from any other of the $n$ vectors, such that this is true for all $n$ vectors?

I know that for $n=\{4,6,\require{cancel} \cancel{8},12,\require{cancel} \cancel{20}\}$ one can simply make use of the Platonic solids embedded in a circle to calculate the corresponding angles/distances.
However, I have not been able to find any resources for the general case. Is this problem really unsolved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is known as the [Tammes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammes_problem). For general $n$, it is a hard problem.

According to Conway and Sloane's book [Sphere packings, lattices and groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985859), the optimal arrangement 
for $n = 4, 6, 8, 12$ and $24$ are known:

- 4 : regular tetrahedron,
- 6 : regular octahedron,
- 8 : square anti-prism,
- 12: regular icosahedron,
- 24: snub cube

The book doesn't have the answer for $n = 20$ but it points out a regular dodecahedron isn't the answer. Furthermore, it is common the best known solutions for larger values of $n$ are not the (highly symmetric) candidates.

If you can get a copy of Conway and Sloane's book, look at the references there.

The info in this book is not most uptodate. Sloane has another book on similar topic (called *Spherical codes*) under preparation. I think I have seen a preliminary copy of it floating around the Web. In any event, look at Sloane's [site](http://neilsloane.com/packings/) for spherical codes as a start.

**Update**

As of July 2015, the Tammers problem for $3 \le N \le 14$ and $24$ has been solved. Following is a short list of papers for the solutions.

- $N = 3,4,6,12$ by L. Fejes Tóth (1943)
  *Über die Abschätzung des kürzesten Abstandes zweier Punkte eines
  auf einer Kugelfläche liegenden Punktsystems*, Jber. Deutch. Math. Verein. **53** (1943)
- $N = 5,7,8,9$ by Schütte and van der Waerden (1951)
  *Auf welcher Kugel haben 5,6,7,8 oder 9 Punkte mit
  Mindestabstand 1 Platz?*
  Math. Ann. **123** (1951), 96-124.
- $N = 10,11$ by Danzer (19??)
  *Finite point-sets on $S^2$ with minimum distance as large as possible*,
  Discr. Math., vol. **60**, 1986, pp. 3-66.
- $N = 13,14$ by Musin and A. S. Tarasov (2012,2015?)
  *Enumeration of irreducible contact graphs on the sphere*,
  Fundam. Prikl. Mat., **18:2** (2013), 125-145 [J. Math. Sci. **203** (2014), 837–850].

  *The Tammes problem for N = 14* (2015?) ([preprint on arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2536))
- $N = 24$ by Robinson (1961)
  *Arrangement of 24 circles on a sphere*, Math. Ann. **144** (1961), 17-48

Edith Mooers has an survey article on Tammes's problem on 1994
summarizes all the solutions for $N \le 12$. An online copy can be found 
[here](http://www.uvm.edu/~pdodds/files/papers/others/1994/mooers1994a.pdf).
Together with Musin's preprint on $N = 14$, one should have a good 
overview on the current status of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I had actually briefly looked at the Tammes problem (but the wiki-page is pretty lackluster), but I didn't realize that the involved radii of the spheres were of course there to satisfy the distance demand. Any insights as to why the symmetric cases work for the $n$'s you listed? Is this connected to a specific symmetry group or something similar? Thanks again!

Comment: @Lovsovs I've no idea why it works for $n = 4, 6, 12$ and I don't think symmetry is the key. As one can see, the most symmetric candidate for $n= 8$ and $20$, the cube and dodecahedron isn't the answer.